# JButton actionPerformed in another class

Tags: java, button, jframe, jbutton

Say I have a class Client that has a function Client.Function1(). How do I get my JButton in class LoginGUI to have it do Function1 in the Client class?

I don't want to initialize a Client instance in the LoginGUI class.

Comment: Make `Client` a singleton maybe? Why do you not want to initialise a `Client` anyway?

Comment: My Client class should only be initialized once. It does a remote server connection of sorts. I could possibly initialize Client in the GUI but is that good design structure?

Comment: If that's the case, I highly recommend you to look into the singleton pattern. Search online!

Comment: Wow Singleton fits perfectly, many thanks. Still curious whether I could get the actionPerformed of the button in the other class, but this is arguably better and a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will demonstrate how you use an action listener in a singleton class.

```
class Client implements ActionListener {
    private static Client instance = new Client();
    public static Client getInstance() { return instance; }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do the thing you want to do here.
    }
}
```

And when you create the `JButton`:

```
JButton b = new JButton();
// configure your button here...
b.addActionListener(Client.getInstance());
```

It is as simple as that.

What if you also want to change the UI and stuff when the button is pressed?

Just add another action listener!

First, write a method in the GUI class and write whatever you want to do with the UI when the button is pressed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // do stuff
}
```

After that, make the GUI class implement `ActionListener`.

Then, just add another action listener:

```
b.addActionListener(this);
```